# Try statement in C?

Tags: c

Is there is a try statement in C? I wan to make an "area calculator" of a trapezoid. I would expect the users to input numbers only:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
 clrscr();
 float base1, base2, height, area;
 printf("This program will compute the area of your trapezoid. Enjoy!");
 printf("\n\tPlease enter the length of base1: ");
 scanf("%f", &base1);
 printf("\tPlease enter the length of base2: ");
 scanf("%f", &base2);
 printf("\tPlease enter the length of height: ");
 scanf("%f", &height);
 area = (base1 + base2) * h / 2;
 printf("\nThe area of your trapezoid is: ", area);
 getch();
}
```

But then, they have the freedom of inputting non-numeric data. Doing so will crash the program. What can I do to check if it is the right data? I believe this can be done with a loop but since there are many solutions to one program i doubt that mine is the most efficient.

Comment: "List of X" questions aren't a great fit to stackoverflow's Q&A format

Comment: You could err **try** it? Seriously though. You can easily find the answer to that if you look. However you should change the second part of your question to be more precise.

Answer (score 6):

C does not have exceptions and hence does not have a `try` statement, it is a *C++* feature, not a C one. You can [set up something similar yourself using `longjmp()`/`setjmp()`](http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html), although personally I'd avoid trying to reinvent that wheel.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't

*Generally* try statements only exist in object-oriented languages such as Python, C++, Objective-C, C#, Visual Basic, Java etc.

Comment: It really has nothing to do with whether the language is object-oriented or not.  You find such a statement in functional languages as well, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure about the relation between OO and exception handling. Take Perl and Haskell as an example. Both have some form of try statement (maybe provided by a library), but I doubt they could be described as "object-oriented".

Answer (score 1):

Error handling is made explicitely in C, with `if()` and `goto`. Exception handling (such as division by 0) depends on the underlying kernel (signal handling on Unix, CPU trap handling on most RTOS).

Ada has an `exception` mechanism with the ability to `raise` user defined exceptions.